Blazor Fluent UI window change
I am migrating from MudBlazor to Fluent UI in my Blazor Standalone WASM project (.NET8).
With MudBlazor I was utilizing IBrowserViewportService in order to get windows size changes.
Whenever the user changed the size of the browser, a function
IBrowserViewportObserver.NotifyBrowserViewportChangeAsync(BrowserViewportEventArgs browserViewportEventArgs)

was triggered helping me scaling an image and depending image overlays correctly.
Is there a similar technology in Fluent UI that I was missing? If not, how could I achieve this otherwise?

I would recommend doing this with css. In particular the newer Container Queries and the :has selector
